# Tree plotting in Python

Tags: python, plot, tree, data-visualization, visualization

I want to plot trees using Python. Decision trees, Organizational charts, etc. Any library that helps me with that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's graphviz - http://www.graphviz.org/. It uses the "DOT" language to plot graphs. You can either generate the DOT code yourself, or use pydot - https://github.com/pydot/pydot. You could also use networkx - http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html#drawing-graphs, which make it easy to draw to either graphviz or matplotlib.

networkx + matplotlib + graphviz gives you the most flexibility and power, but you need to install a lot.

If you want a quick solution, try:

Install Graphviz.

```
open('hello.dot','w').write("digraph G {Hello->World}")
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["path/to/dot.exe","-Tpng","hello.dot","-o","graph1.png"]) 
# I think this is right - try it form the command line to debug
```

Then you install pydot, because pydot already does this for you. Then you can use networkx to "drive" pydot.

Comment: NetworX looks pretty good. The only thing is that I require an external library to generate image files. Can I generate an arc between nodes?

Comment: Which library? NetworkX can handle a few different ones. They seem to like Matplotlib, which has an install guide here: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html.

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't support graphs, standalone at least.

Comment: NetworkX. *Graphviz* is famous historically for reading the "DOT" files, but IMO *NetworkX*, *Ete*, and *iGraph* produce far better results by modern standards, and don't require mixing another language with Python.

Comment: Link to NetworkX website is broken. New link: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#drawing-graphs

Answer (score 109):

I develop [ETE](http://etetoolkit.org), which is a python package intended, among other stuff, for programmatic tree rendering and visualization. You can create your own [layout functions](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_drawing.html) and produce custom [tree images](http://etetoolkit.org/gallery/):
[image]

It has a focus on phylogenetics, but it can actually deal with any type of hierarchical tree (clustering, decision trees, etc.)

Comment: @Fxs7576 There is a working branch that will be merged soon that adds Qt5 support. https://github.com/etetoolkit/ete/pull/284

Comment: Is it not available for Windows? Your install guide doesn't have a windows section and if I run the conda install line, it doesn't find the package.

Comment: For windows, it looks like you can install using pip install ete3.

Comment: Literally the only package I found that could be `pip install`ed and it would run out of the box.

Comment: looks promissing

Comment: I installed ete3 (released in 2020), but since I have Qt5 installed, it throws an error. When will ete4 be avilable as pip installable package?

Comment: Oh my god, this is art.

Answer (score 47):

For **basic visualization** I would consider using [treelib](https://treelib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/),

It is very **straightforward and easy to use**:

```
 from treelib import Node, Tree

 tree = Tree()

 tree.create_node("Harry", "harry")  # No parent means its the root node
 tree.create_node("Jane",  "jane"   , parent="harry")
 tree.create_node("Bill",  "bill"   , parent="harry")
 tree.create_node("Diane", "diane"  , parent="jane")
 tree.create_node("Mary",  "mary"   , parent="diane")
 tree.create_node("Mark",  "mark"   , parent="jane")

 tree.show()
```

Output:

```
Harry
├── Bill
└── Jane
    ├── Diane
    │   └── Mary
    └── Mark
```

Comment: Highly appreciate your input, easy to use indeed. Also, there is a nice method once you've built a tree to generate graphviz format of the tree: `tree.to_graphviz()`. So you can use it then in any online or offline tool.

Answer (score 6):

[Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/tree-plots/) can plot tree diagrams using igraph. You can use it offline these days too. The example below is intended to be run in a Jupyter notebook

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import igraph
from igraph import *
# I do not endorse importing * like this

#Set Up Tree with igraph

nr_vertices = 25
v_label = map(str, range(nr_vertices))
G = Graph.Tree(nr_vertices, 2) # 2 stands for children number
lay = G.layout('rt')

position = {k: lay[k] for k in range(nr_vertices)}
Y = [lay[k][1] for k in range(nr_vertices)]
M = max(Y)

es = EdgeSeq(G) # sequence of edges
E = [e.tuple for e in G.es] # list of edges

L = len(position)
Xn = [position[k][0] for k in range(L)]
Yn = [2*M-position[k][1] for k in range(L)]
Xe = []
Ye = []
for edge in E:
    Xe+=[position[edge[0]][0],position[edge[1]][0], None]
    Ye+=[2*M-position[edge[0]][1],2*M-position[edge[1]][1], None] 

labels = v_label

#Create Plotly Traces

lines = go.Scatter(x=Xe,
                   y=Ye,
                   mode='lines',
                   line=dict(color='rgb(210,210,210)', width=1),
                   hoverinfo='none'
                   )
dots = go.Scatter(x=Xn,
                  y=Yn,
                  mode='markers',
                  name='',
                  marker=dict(symbol='dot',
                                size=18, 
                                color='#6175c1',    #'#DB4551', 
                                line=dict(color='rgb(50,50,50)', width=1)
                                ),
                  text=labels,
                  hoverinfo='text',
                  opacity=0.8
                  )

# Create Text Inside the Circle via Annotations

def make_annotations(pos, text, font_size=10, 
                     font_color='rgb(250,250,250)'):
    L=len(pos)
    if len(text)!=L:
        raise ValueError('The lists pos and text must have the same len')
    annotations = go.Annotations()
    for k in range(L):
        annotations.append(
            go.Annotation(
                text=labels[k], # or replace labels with a different list 
                                # for the text within the circle  
                x=pos[k][0], y=2*M-position[k][1],
                xref='x1', yref='y1',
                font=dict(color=font_color, size=font_size),
                showarrow=False)
        )
    return annotations  

# Add Axis Specifications and Create the Layout

axis = dict(showline=False, # hide axis line, grid, ticklabels and  title
            zeroline=False,
            showgrid=False,
            showticklabels=False,
            )

layout = dict(title= 'Tree with Reingold-Tilford Layout',  
              annotations=make_annotations(position, v_label),
              font=dict(size=12),
              showlegend=False,
              xaxis=go.XAxis(axis),
              yaxis=go.YAxis(axis),          
              margin=dict(l=40, r=40, b=85, t=100),
              hovermode='closest',
              plot_bgcolor='rgb(248,248,248)'          
              )

# Plot

data=go.Data([lines, dots])
fig=dict(data=data, layout=layout)
fig['layout'].update(annotations=make_annotations(position, v_label))
py.iplot(fig, filename='Tree-Reingold-Tilf')
# use py.plot instead of py.iplot if you're not using a Jupyter notebook
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGue3.png)

Comment: I get an incomprehensible error message from this: `DeprecationWarning                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-cfbb1d309447> in <module>()
----> 4 import igraph
DeprecationWarning: To avoid name collision with the igraph project, this visualization library has been renamed to 'jgraph'. Please upgrade when convenient.` I do not know what to upgrade: `igraph`, `jgraph`, or something else. I have the latest versions of everything. Rewriting your code to refer to `jgraph` didn't work. `pip install jgraph` didn't work: `jgraph` has no `Graph` member. etc. :(

Comment: Found a potential answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200707/error-with-igraph-library-deprecated-library

Comment: I got this to work, but it required setting up an account with plotly, so I looked for free alternatives. python-igraph (NOT the same as igraph) has some plotting capability in it http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html. It's hard to install; on Mac OS X, after a painful trip down the rabbit hole, "brew install cairo" turned out to be necessary and sufficient.

Comment: why am I getting 
    TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

Answer (score 3):

For a 2021 solution, I wrote a Python wrapper of the TreantJS library. The package creates an HTML file with a tree visualization. The user can optionally invoke R's `webshot` library to render high-res screenshots of the trees. The package is quite new, so any PRs, bug reports, or feature requests in the issues would be much appreciated! See: https://github.com/Luke-Poeppel/treeplotter.

The package has some annoying installation requirements (see `Installation.md`), so I wrote a MacOS installation helper (tested on Catalina and Big Sur). Any tips on reducing these constraints would also be welcome.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's expirmental, but Google has a [GraphViz api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/graphviz.html). It's convenient if you just want to quickly visualize a graph, but don't want to install any software.

Comment: This API is deprecated and turned off