# Identifying branches different in tag structure

Tags: python, parsing, dom, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm hoping to check if two html are different by tags only without considering the text and pick out those branch(es).

For example :

```
html_1 = """
<p>i love it</p>
"""
html_2 = """ 
<p>i love it really</p>
"""
```

They share the same tag structure, so they're seen to be the same. However:

```
html_1 = """
<div>
<p>i love it</p>
</div>
<p>i love it</p>
"""
html_2 = """ 
<div>
<p>i <em>love</em> it</p>
</div>
<p>i love it</p>
"""
```

I'd expect it to return the `<div>` branch, because the tag structures are different. Could `lxml`, `BeautifulSoup` or some other lib achieve this? I'm trying to find a way to actually pick out the different branches.

Thanks

Comment: Not getting.. What you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm hoping to just pick out the branches that contain different tags but not different text. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: ok means we want to find if two HTML's are Same or Different in Tagging structure.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I shall fix my question.

Answer (score 1):

A more reliable approach would be to construct a [Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Tree_(data_structure)) of tag names out of the document as discussed here:

- [HTML Parse tree using Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172028/html-parse-tree-using-python-2-7)

Here is an example working solution based on [`treelib.Tree`](http://xiaming.me/treelib/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from treelib import Tree


def traverse(parent, tree):
    tree.create_node(parent.name, parent.name, parent=parent.parent.name if parent.parent else None)

    for node in parent.find_all(recursive=False):
        tree.create_node(node.name, parent=parent.name)
        traverse(node, tree)


def compare(html1, html2):
    tree1 = Tree()
    traverse(BeautifulSoup(html1, "html.parser"), tree1)
    tree2 = Tree()
    traverse(BeautifulSoup(html2, "html.parser"), tree2)

    return tree1.to_json() == tree2.to_json()

print compare("<p>i love it</p>", "<p>i love it really</p>")
print compare("<p>i love it</p>", "<p>i <em>love</em> it</p>")
```

Prints:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually hoping to pick out the actual branches that contain the different tagging structures, could this be achieved with minor modifications?

Comment: @Kate you can iterate over the trees (`tree1` and `tree2`) and compare them node by node.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to check tagging structure of two HTML content are same for not

**Demo:**

```
def getTagSequence(content):
    """                  
    Get all Tag Sequence
    """
    root = PARSER.fromstring(content)
    tag_sequence = []
    for elm in root.getiterator():
        tag_sequence.append(elm.tag)
    return tag_sequence

html_1_tags = getTagSequence(html_1)
html_2_tags = getTagSequence(html_2)

if html_1_tags==html_2_tags:
     print "Tagging structure is same."
else:
     print "Tagging structure is diffrent."
     print "HTML 1 Tagging:", html_1_tags
     print "HTML 2 Tagging:", html_2_tags
```

**Note:**

Above code just check tagging sequence only, Not checking parent and its children relationship i.e

```
html_1 = """ <p> This <span>is <em>p</em></span> tag</p>"""
html_2 = """ <p> This <span>is </span><em>p</em> tag</p>"""
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually after something that identifies the branch different in tagging structure. I guess the examples I gave aren't particularly good since the structures are somewhat flat and not trees.

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, the code identifies whether the two pieces of HTML are different in tagging structure but not identifying the actual branches that contain the different tagging structure, right? I'm actually hoping to achieve the latter.

Comment: @Kate: branches means?? We have to pick any tag from the content and compare that tag, tagging structure in two different HTML's ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. For each tag in one document, compare that tag's structure with each tag's structure in another document. I think traditional iteration would be quite inefficient, so I wonder if there's something better.