# Plot lattice tree in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, hierarchical-data, mathematical-lattices

I'm seeking ideas to plot a tuple tree `t = ((4,), (3, 5,), (2, 4, 6,), (1, 3, 5, 7,))` as the following image (assuming this binomial tree size can change). I'm trying to avoid dependencies on non-core packages (just sticking to pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scikit, and such).

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670280/tree-plotting-in-python

Comment: @Leb : Interesting post, but it refers to `graphviz` package or software. I just need a simple way of plotting a tree so as to add it to a package without any extra dependencies. Still, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this piece of code which gives a pretty good result:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5, 5])
for i in range(3):
    x = [1, 0, 1]
    for j in range(i):
        x.append(0)
        x.append(1)
    x = np.array(x) + i
    y = np.arange(-(i+1), i+2)[::-1]
    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo-')
plt.show()
```

[image]