# Error with igraph library - deprecated library

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, igraph

I have changed my computer to a Linux Mint x64 OS and I have throubles with a python library, igraph library, when i try to execute and old program I made.

> DeprecationWarning: To avoid name collision with the igraph project, this visualization library has been renamed to 'jgraph'. Please upgrade when convenient.

I can't find information about how to change my code for the new library. 
On a Win8 PC, via pip installation, it works perfectly but I can't make it working on my PC with Mint.
The normal installation made with

> sudo apt-get install python-igraph

install 0.6.5-1 library version.
I've also tried installing it with pip but it gives me same error
but installed version is igraph-0.1.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl

I'm using only Graph class

```
from igraph import Graph
```

What have I to do to change my code to make it working with the new library? Am I missing something?

edit: it's working on my laptop with Mint x86 OS, library version 0.6.5-1

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**Update:** This information is outdated since November 2021. The correct way to install igraph's Python interface is now `pip install igraph`.

---

I think you have installed the wrong igraph libray.

This [igraph(0.1.11)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/igraph?) is the one you installed, while this [igraph(0.7.1)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-igraph) is the one you need (and the well-known iGraph).

- Using pip (once you've installed it), Just do:

  sudo pip uninstall igraph
- Then install the python-igraph-0.7.1 package, using either pip or apt-get as mentionned in comments below:

  sudo pip install python-igraph

Hope it works.

Comment: it works if I donwload the source code from the website and I add the library _igraph.so installed with python-igraph package via apt-get to the same folder

Comment: Great. So the problem seemed to be that you actually had the wrong library (the one provided by  Patrick Fuller) wich is missleading since the needed one is usualy the one provided by  Tamas Nepusz. 
I update my answer so you can mark it as correct.

Comment: 2017 checking in. this doesnt seem to work in macOS Sierra.

Comment: DON'T `sudo` pip. If you've accidentally `sudo`'d in the past, it's safer to `pip install python-igraph --user`

Comment: First "pip install python-igraph" then "import igraph as ig" worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo -H pip uninstall igraph
```

then:

```
sudo pip install python-igraph
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusion, I'd like to point out that the other answers are now outdated, and the question is obsolete.

Since November 2021, the Python interface of the igraph network analysis library can be installed using

```
pip install igraph
```

Using `pip install python-igraph` is now deprecated.

References:

- https://pypi.org/project/igraph/
- https://pypi.org/project/python-igraph/