# Why can I not use igraph in Python?

Tags: python, windows, graph, pycharm, igraph

My environment is windows 10 + pycharm + Python 3.7. I am trying to use igraph by studying https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html. It can be installed successfully. But, when I run

```
from igraph import *
```

I have got such information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\feng\myCode\infoExtract\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-50-283d00fb94b6>", line 1, in <module>
from igraph import *
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\feng\myCode\infoExtract\venv\lib\site-packages\igraph\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
raise DeprecationWarning("To avoid name collision with the igraph project, "
DeprecationWarning: To avoid name collision with the igraph project, this visualization library has been renamed to 'jgraph'. Please upgrade when convenient.
```

when I try

```
g = Graph()
```

I have got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\feng\myCode\infoExtract\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-51-abc271209dcf>", line 1, in <module>
g = Graph()
NameError: name 'Graph' is not defined
```

I have checked the answer from [Error with igraph library - deprecated library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200707/error-with-igraph-library-deprecated-library). Then install python-igraph according to https://pypi.org/project/python-igraph/. But I have got this:

[image]

At the same time, I have also uninstalled igraph:

[image]

You can see that igraph can be uploaded. But Graph function still does not work. Why is this happening?

Comment: Judging from the linked duplicate, it looks like you may have the wrong package installed - not sure what package manager you're using (pip, anaconda etc.), but you need to install `python-igraph`.

Comment: I update my question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: The linked duplicate suggests you may also have to uninstall the original `igraph` package - have you tried that as well?

Comment: Thanks. But I have already uninstalled igraph package

Comment: As per past comments, when asking questions, we would rather they were written in a technical and neutral style. Chatty material that begs, pleads and implores readers for an answer may be thought of as somewhat coercive, and is not really appropriate for the volunteer audience. Please keep it succinct.