# Create a Graph with a Syntax Tree on Python

Tags: python, graph, syntax, tree, dot

I have the output of my parser as something like this:

[S[F[NP[DT your][N offer]][VP[V is][ADJ good]]][NO sonny]]

And I need to convert it to an image of a graph with the syntax tree, something similar to what this site(http://mshang.ca/syntree/) would generate.

Is there any library that could be helpful or that would automatically do that for me ? I need this to run local, so i can't scrap the site and save the image.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670280/tree-plotting-in-python).

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

Is ASCII adequate?

Example cut from newly released [Parsey McParseface](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet):

```
Input: Bob brought the pizza to Alice .
Parse:
brought VBD ROOT
 +-- Bob NNP nsubj
 +-- pizza NN dobj
 |   +-- the DT det
 +-- to IN prep
 |   +-- Alice NNP pobj
 +-- . . punct
```

Code is here:
[A program to generate ASCII trees from conll files.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/conll2tree.py#L82)