# Visualizing decision tree not using graphviz/web

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, decision-tree

Due to some restriction I cannot use graphviz ,  webgraphviz.com
to visualize decision tree (work network is closed from the other world).

**Question:** Is there some alternative utilite or some Python code for at least very simple visualization may be just ASCII visualization of decision tree (python/sklearn) ?

I mean, I can use sklearn in particular: tree.export_graphviz( )
which produces text file with tree structure, from which one can read a tree, 
but doing it by "eyes" is not pleasant ...

PS
Pay attention that

```
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

will NOT work, since create_png uses implicitly graphviz

Comment: I have used [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html) before, but it requires a fair bit of tuning

Comment: You may find more answers [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670280/tree-plotting-in-python) as well

Comment: Also here some info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224526/how-to-extract-the-decision-rules-from-scikit-learn-decision-tree?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This article may be useful for you: http://explained.ai/decision-tree-viz/index.html